# Database connection refused for Laravel artisan command with Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am trying to run Laravel using Docker locally. Everything works fine expect the database. This is how my docker-compose looks like:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    container_name: my-app
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - my-network
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: my-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - my-network
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: my-nginx
    ports:
      - 8001:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - my-network
```

My .env file looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=
```

When I run `php artisan migrate:fresh` within the `app` container, I am getting the following message:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Can someone see what is the problem here?

UPDATE: When I run `docker-compose ps` I can see

```
NAME                COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
my-app             "docker-php-entrypoi…"   app                 running             9000/tcp
my-db              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db                  restarting          
my-nginx           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   nginx               running             0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp, :::8001->80/tcp
```

This is the log when I run `docker-compose logs db`

```
my-db  | 2021-07-29T20:18:37.340769Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) initializing of server in progress as process 104
my-db  | 2021-07-29T20:18:37.354423Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
my-db  | 2021-07-29T20:18:37.354605Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
my-db  | 2021-07-29T20:18:37.356184Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
my-db  | 2021-07-29T20:18:37.358746Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: Pls show full docker-compose

Comment: and show result of `docker-compose ps`

Comment: Okey, I think your problem is in volume  - ./docker/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d - mysql cannot start. show `docker-compose logs db`  after `docker-compose down -v | docker-compose up -d`

Comment: @Maksim I have updated question with logs

Comment: Nice, problem in volume. Try to add `tmpfs: /var/lib/mysql` after `image` in db - if this help - than need to debug docker volumes.

Comment: Btw, and for debug - try comment out your docker-entrypoint-initdb.d